# Compariong Java and .NET web platform

Tags: java, .net

I have developed at .NET platform until now and I want to learn differences and similarities or alternatives with java.

```
.NET platform web        And       JAVA platform web
-----------------                  -----------------
ASP                                ??? 
ASPX Web form                      ??? 
MVC                                ???
Entity Framework                   ???
WEB API                            ???
```

I read some technologies JSP, JSF, Spring, Hibernate which is  old tech. or which is new?

Comment: There's probably a dozen technologies that are comparable to the things you've listed in .NET on Java's end.

Comment: looks more relevant for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hibernate is not "old tech".

Answer (score 0):

Actually everything depends on your understanding that is how comfortable are you in writing a code in a certain language. A developer having comfort in C# will tell you to use ASP or someone expert in springs or struts will recommend you Java. But at the end of the day it is you who has to decide.

I can explain it in real world as using smart phones :   almost every smartphone is similar in features but the comfort factor makes it suitable for respective user.

Hope it helps. And If you wish to start coding in Java here is very nice blog about that :http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2014/05/15/modern-java-pt3/